# How can I upload a file to S3 using a presigned URL without loading it into memory

Tags: java, amazon-s3, upload, out-of-memory

I'm using presigned AWS S3 urls to upload files from a device with limited memory using Java. However, I occasionally have large files that I need the upload. The problem is that loading these files into memory is causing out of memory exceptions.

I've found that it's possible to stream a file directly to S3 (eg, https://www.example-code.com/java/s3_file_stream_upload.asp ), but I can't find any information about how to do that using a presigned url.

Is there a way to upload large files (under 5GB) to S3 using presigned urls without loading the file into memory first?

Comment: If you're uploading files that large, use multipart. The jets3t library can make dealing with this much simpler.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not the one generating the presigned url, so I can only get 1 at a time. We're making requests to another service that generates the urls for us. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use just the single url and stream the file

Answer (score 0):

*This can be achieved using Multipart. You don't event need to store the file locally on your server, this will avoid* **Mermory Exception.**
*Below code is in Java*

```
public boolean uploadFileDirectlyToS3(MultipartFile multipartFile, String keyName) {
        ObjectMetadata data = new ObjectMetadata();
        try {
            data.setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType());
            data.setContentLength(multipartFile.getSize());
            s3Client.putObject(CORE_BUNDLE.getString("bucket.name"), keyName, multipartFile.getInputStream(), data); 
//KeyName is the specific and unique path where you wanna place your file in s3
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while uploading file to s3 having name: "+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```